# Continuity in Lemma 3.6 of Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Lemma 3.6 of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry book: Let $X$ be a variety and let $Y$ be an affine variety. A map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a morphism if and only if $x_{i} \circ f$ is a regular function on $X$ for each $i$ where $x_{i}$ are the coordinate functions.

(<=)

For the continuity part of $f$, can you explain exactly what he means by "Since the closed sets of Y are defined by vanishing of polynomial functions, and since regular functions are continuous" to conclude that $f^{-1}$ takes closed sets to closed sets? What do those two facts tell us that we can conclude?

Suppose $U$ is a closed set of $Y$ and $g$ is a polynomial vanishing on $U$, then $g \circ f$ is regular (since g is a polynomial) and $g \circ f$ clearly vanishes on $f^{-1}(U)$. Can I argue this way, that since the diagram below 'commutes'

\begin{array}  &X & \\ \downarrow^{f}&\searrow^{r}\\
 Y&\rightarrow^{g}&k \end{array}
where $r = g \circ f$ is the regular function by assumption, $g$ polynomial vanishing at the closed set $U$ of $Y$.

then since r is continuous (since regular), then f must be continuous?

Explicitly, what are the functions on X vanishing on U, and I believe we need either polynomials or homogeneous polynomials depending on the variety of X. Are they just $p = (\frac{p}{q}) \cdot q = r \cdot q =  (g \circ f)\cdot q$? (where r is regular function above)

Comment: @Ruben g is a polynomial $g:Y \rightarrow k$ and $r$ is a regular function $r: X\rightarrow k$ ; I am not familiar with $Spec$ $k$

Comment: what is your definition of a variety and an affine variety?

Comment: @Ruben An affine variety is an irreducible closed set of affine space $A^n$ (with Zariski topology), and a variety is either an affine/projective variety or a quasi-affine or quasi-projective variety (where quasi-affine variety is an open subset of an affine variety).

Comment: Essentially it suffices to check continuity on a basis of the topology (given by nonvanishing loci of polynomials). Then use the diagram as you said to conclude.

Comment: @metalder9 Oh this is HH chapter 1. My mistake.